# Modular architecture in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, oop, codeigniter

### the idea

I'm playing with a concept of modular website builder - now mostly in *theory*, which would containt pages / collections based on modules (either preprogrammed or done specifically when needed).

Every module with come with it's ties to DB, views/templates and core data processing, I'm thinking about `factory` pattern:

basic module wrapper - having normalized names -> callDB, processData, returnToTemplate

each module then inherits this wrapper and just adds it's calls to DB, it's data processing and finally will return to data, then in application, I will just do something like:

```
$this->modules->each->callDB(); //obviously, pseudo-PHP
```

### the problem

What am I struggling with, however, is incorporating this whole idea into CodeIgniter's MVC approach and it's data structure, so it won't be/feel (i know, subjective) unnatural and/or meaningless.

Any ideas?

(under tree structre i - i know, that i can do whatever i like. However, I don't know if I like dir `modules` with subir for each module, or templates in `application/templates` and modules in `application/modules` - and those modules, it actually doesn't make sense to me, since my modules are somewhat different than CI modules... you know...)

### edit1

So... is this so hardcore or so dumb that there are no answers??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What exactly are you trying to achieve? There is plenty of code out there to help you achieve modular architecture (HMVC) in your CodeIgniter application.

[Modular Separation](http://codeigniter.com/forums/viewthread/121820/) - wiredesignz

[Matchbox](http://code.google.com/p/matchbox/) - Zacharias Knudsen

Anything else you need to add in relating to wrapping the module is purely in the implementation. I'd look into using MY_Controller and possibly taking it a step further to [implement multiple base classes](http://philsturgeon.co.uk/news/2010/02/CodeIgniter-Base-Classes-Keeping-it-DRY), so your frontend controllers know to wrap the module with whatever data from the DB.

Comment: main SO's CI advisor, Phil? :)

Comment: I am the unofficial StackOverflow CodeIgniter guy :-p

Comment: The links are dead now

Answer (score 0):

There is a HMVC extension to codeigniter, check http://codeigniter.com/wiki/Modular_Extensions_-_HMVC/

Also you cand separate concerns in a modular way, by overloading CI's loader class (and routing if needed)  and storing your MVC files in subfolders of application/models,  application/views and application/controllers

Comment: Modular Extensions is slightly older and has been replaced by Modular Separation linked in my answer. The main difference is that ME supports PHP 4 & 5 but MS is much lighter and adds awesome new features such as 404 routing and multiple module directories instead of just one "application/modules". There is very little point in using ME HMVC, use MS instead.

Comment: Phil, there is. people who use PHP4 could use ME.

Comment: @Thorpe: true about PHP4, however not my need :]